# How do I transplant my English lavender that grew very close to each other

Tags: plant-care, transplanting, roots, lavender

[image]
Is it too late to transplant my english lavender? I started them from seed in April, and didn't expect the ones that are gonna survive are the ones that are beside each other. So I am concerned that if I try to transplant it, I might damage some entangled roots. Anyone with a similar experience in the past? Any tips on this would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem to repot them into separate pots. Plant to the same depth, use a good quality, free draining compost and they should be fine. Don't let them dry out, obviously. More information [here](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/popular/lavender/english).